# Model field level permission and Field value level permission in Django and DRF

Tags: django, permissions

I am doing a project which require some user to access (view) a model's field but they cannot update the field. Is there a way to do this?
This will not be used in the admin site.

Also, I want to provide permissions based on a model's field value. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different possibilities to check the permissions, though they all require you writing the permission checking code yourself. There might be some django packages providing the functionality for you, but I don't know any.

You could create one permissions for each field that you would like to permit / deny in the model's `META.permissions` attribute and then check the permissions per user.

The checks can be done in different places. Either in your view directly, in the model's `save`method or in the form's `clean_<field_name>` method. I would prefer the `clean_<field_name>` method. e.g.:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = <YOUR MODEL>

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_myfield(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        # check if the user has the required permission to change the field
        if self.user.has_perm(<YOUR PERMISSION>):
            return cd.get('myfield')
        # if not, return the original value
        if self.instance:
            return self.instance.myfield
        # If it can happen that there is no instance yet,
        # you should return a sensible default here
        return None
```

For this solution, you would need to pass the `request.user` to the form on instantiation.

Comment: I will consider this. Thanks!